# Possible to Display LinkedIn Company Feed on Website?

Tags: linkedin-api

### Question

How can I display the feed from my company's LinkedIn page on my website? If this must be done via the API, could you please advise which [LinkedIn platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/) should be used?

In case it matters, the website is a [Salesforce Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_resources.htm&type=5).

### Things I've Tried

- Opening a case with LinkedIn support - they pointed me here
- Looking into third-party solutions - [the only one I could find](https://taggbox.com/blog/embed-linkedin-feed-on-website/) no longer supports this
- Looking into LinkedIn plugins - the ['Company Profile' plugin](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins) has been disabled
- Submitting a case to the LinkedIn Sales Navigator team - no response yet

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the v2 api support it?